# How do you find the database a Django object is using?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django supports using [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/) simultaneously, and the docs explain how to specify the database when saving or retrieving an object. However, given a Django model instance, how do you determine which database it's currently using? I've inspected an instance, but it doesn't seem to have any `.using` attribute or anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Using routers documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers), you can use `model_instance._state.db` to inspect the database which the current model instance is using.